# How do you set the z-index of a usercontrol within a grid?

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls, z-index

When I try setting the z-index to a higher index, it gives me an error: Member 'Panel.GetZIndex(UIElement)' cannot be accessed with an instance reference; qualify it with a type name instead. Even though I have tried the actual class GridPanel.GetZIndex

```
  private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
       int zOrder = Panel.GetZIndex(pickupDineControl);
        Panel.SetZIndex(pickupDineControl, (int)4);

    }


<Grid x:Name="panel">
   <local:menuControl Grid.Row="1" Panel.ZIndex="1"  />
    <local:pickupDineControl Grid.Row="1" x:Name="pdcontrol" 
     Panel.ZIndex="2"  />
    <local:mainControl Grid.Row="1"  x:Name="maincontrol" Panel.ZIndex="3"/>

</Grid>
```

Answer (score 0):

GetZIndex method is static, you cannot call it on instances. You should use class name instead. For example :

```
int zOrder = Panel.GetZIndex(pdcontrol);
```

Comment: I have tried everything, can you please use my code to make it more clear. Thanks in advance

Comment: The edited version should work. You should do the same thing for SetZIndex method as well.

Comment: It does not show any errors but wont bring up the control to the front on window load, please look at the edited version of my code

Comment: You should give the name of the control as input. If it also didnt work, then problem might be within your controls.